# Quel est l'équivalent de « peer » en français?

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique, noms

Je travaille en informatique et nous utilisons souvent le terme anglais « peer ».
Par exemple, « each peer communicates its information through the channel ».

Quelle serait la traduction exacte en français du mot *peer* ? Serait-ce « pair » ?

« Chaque pair communique ses informations via le canal » est une phrase qui me semble avoir du sens, ainsi que pour le correcteur orthographique de mon traitement de texte.

Cependant, lorsque j'utilise le mot comme dans la phrase suivante, il m'indique une erreur :

> *A peer is possessed by an organization.*
>
> ---
>
> Un pair est possédé par une organisation.

Est-ce normal qu'il ne comprenne pas le mot dans ce contexte ? Est-ce que mon utilisation du mot est valide dans ce contexte ?

---

Mise à jour suite aux commentaires:

Ici "peer" qualifie une entité logique et physique (c'est un ensemble de composants logiciel ET un ordinateur), non pas un humain.

Un synonyme de "peer" serait "node". Cependant, il est clairement indiqué dans la terminologie (du "package" que j'utilise) que l'entité "peer" peut aussi être appelée "peer node". "Peer" est un "diminutif".

Par conséquent, "peer" s'approcherait plus de "entity". Cela n'a pas de lien avec "token".

L'organisation possède le "peer" car c'est elle qui l'administre et personne d'autre.

Un canal est un sous-réseau logique de communication. C'est à travers ce ce sous-réseau (ce canal) que les "peers" communiquent.

Comment: Voir [pair](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pair)

Comment: @Survenant9r7 ma lecture du contexte, c'est que le *peer* ici est l'un des acteurs d'un protocole, ce qui englobe la notion de client, serveur ou nœud d'un réseau comme dans l'expression *TLS peer*. Sinon d'accord que ce serait bien de clarifier cela dans la question.

Comment: @qoba Informations ajoutées.

Comment: Mais je pense que la réponse de @qoba me semble correcte. Elle est logique et correspond à la terminologie "officielle".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Pair" est la traduction littérale du mot anglais *peer*, mais elle pose souvent problème en français, en particulier du fait des homonymes père (nom), paire (nom), et pair (adjectif signifiant l'opposé d'impair) qui sont tous beaucoup plus courants que pair au sens de peer.

Dans certains domaines, cela peut être la traduction qui est utilisée. Par exemple, on pourra parler des "pairs du Royaume-Uni". Ou alors, en parlant d'une revue scientifique, on pourra dire qu'elle fonctionne à la base "d'évaluation par les pairs" (*peer review*), quoique l'anglicisme consistant à emprunter le terme anglais s'entende aussi souvent.

Dans le domaine particulier de l'informatique, l'expression "peer-to-peer" peut être traduite par "pair-à-pair", mais dans mon expérience elle est plutôt soit empruntée telle quelle à l'anglais, soit abrégée en "P2P", soit paraphrasée par une expression figurant des mots comme "décentralisé" ou "sans autorité centrale".

En revanche l'utilisation du mot *peer* tout seul me paraît plus rare, que ce soit sous forme d'emprunt ou de traduction ; peut-être est-ce parce qu'il y à la aussi un problème d'homonymie pour distinguer "le *peer*" et "le pire", problème qui ne se pose pas autant avec des expressions figées comme "une *peer review*" ou "en *peer to peer*" ? En tout cas, pour le contexte donné en exemple dans la question je suggérerais des expressions comme "nœud" ou "nœud du système".

Answer (score 2):

La phrase en anglais "A peer is possessed by an organization" ne veut rien dire pour moi. Quel est le sens supposé? (en anglais ou en français) Cela tendrait à vouloir dire qu'un groupe possède quelqu'un, et ce n'est pas habituel de s'exprimer de cette façon.

Si ce que vous voulez dire c'est que l'un des membres appartient à l'association, j'utiliserais le verbe « to belong », et pour le français je viens de l'écrire. Le terme de membre est souvent plus facile à utiliser que celui de « pair » en dehors du pluriel « ses pairs ». Le reste n'est qu'anglicisme. On pourrait aussi écrire « son pareil », « son semblable », « son homologue, confrère, collègue, compatriote, etc » selon le contexte.

Comment: Bien d'accord pour homologue, semblable et aussi sur le fait que le sens de *peer* décrit dans la question n'est pas clair.